# Who is the 6th pallbearer for Leo McGarry's coffin?

Tags: character, the-west-wing

Leo McGarry's funeral occurs in The West Wing S07E18. He has six pallbearers. I can identify five of them, but not the sixth

[image]

From left-to-right:

- Josh Lyman (Chief of Staff to the President-Elect, Matt Santos)
- Barry Goodwin (Chairman of the DCCC)
- **UNKNOWN**
- President Bartlet
- Charlie Young (former body-man to President Bartlet)
- President-Elect Matt Santos

Here's a close-up of the man in question. I don't recognize him.

[image]

**Do we know who he is?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not confirmed since he's uncredited but I believe this is

[**Gary Patrick Anderson**](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1206121/mediaindex?refine=publicity&ref_=nm_ov_resph)

playing Leo's son-in-law.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did he have a daughter that was married?

Comment: Yeah. http://westwing.wikia.com/wiki/Mallory_O%27Brien